# What is the result of the following code?

Tags: c

Why the result is 7??? I can't find the log if that :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int i, j, a = 1, b = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < 3; j++)
            a = a + b;
    printf("a=%d", a);
}
```

Comment: why don't try yourself?

Comment: Why dont use a debugger?

Comment: a starts at 1, b stays at 1. the loop runs 1..3 x 1..2 == 6 times. each time a increments by 1 ( b is fixed ), so a==1+6

Comment: Well you add 1 , 6 times(2 times in j loop * 3 times in i loop) to 1. 1+6*1=7 .

Comment: What I like to do if I can't find why code in a loop is getting a result is taking a pen and paper and computing the code by hand. Keep track of all the variables. Hope that helps.

Comment: What did you *expect* it to be? Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, line by line? Did you try it out on paper?

Answer (score 2):

The structure is like below

```
- Outer `for` loop
 - inner `for` loop
     - instruction
```

so the "instruction" (statement/block) will get executed inner `for` loop count times, for outer `for` loop count times.

What is basically says is, add the value of `b` to the latest value of `a` (in a recurring way) to get the current value of a. Now , do that for "outer" number of time, for which, do the same for "inner" number of times.

Outer `for` loop ==> 3 times,
inner `for` loop ==> 2 times

So, final value =`3*2 (increment)` + `(initial)` = `(3*2)*1 + 1` = `7`.

Answer (score 1):

The result is 7 because b is initialized as 1 and stays 1 the whole time. The outer loop is run 3 times (1, 2, 3), the inner loop is run 2 times (1 and 2), so there are 6 runs where b is added to a (which is initialized as 1). 1 + 6 = 7.

Answer (score 1):

In such scenarios, you should add a watch and debug your code line by line. I believe the shortcut is F11. Regards to why the output of your code is 7...
The inner loop runs six times. J loops twice - 1, 2, (ends when it is 3), and I loops thrice (1, 2, 3, 4 - end)... for a total of 2 X 3 = 6.

Since b is '1', you are basically adding the number 1 to a six times. Since a started with '1', the output is:

a = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7